# How to Run Jenkins And See Tests running visually

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I am Using Commande "sudo service jenkins start" in centos to run jenkins but its runned in backround as service but me i want to visual what happen in selenium tests and open browser.any idea plz!

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand there are two things that you are looking for:

1. Test results
2. Browser on which tests are executed.

For #1 you should have your test generated report and on completion send that report on email.
Regarding #2 since you are using selenium. Using selenium you should be able to open browser as your tests executes and see the progress. Watching browser is not the suggested way. Test should be executed in background and on completion report should tell you what went wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: because we want to make demo for team juste to configure jenkins to run and later run as services if there is way to make that plz!

Comment: You can have parameter in your tests that can work the way you want.i.e show the browser or run the test in background